# One day, my mother comes. Is it correct? past or present

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

Is this sentence correct?

*Suppose* I am elected as the president of America now. One day, my mother **comes** and **knocks** my door and **says** "Hey! Our neighbor is here to see you and spend some time with you.

Shouldn't he use the past tense since it's imaginary as he said *suppose*

Comment: to knock **on a door**. You can check these things before posting. Also, please look up: historical present. So, yes, the present tense can be used to tell a story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tense is about when the action occurs *relative to the speaker*.

If you are talking about what *already happened*, then the past tense is appropriate.

When you introduce a hypothetical, the story has not (yet?) happened, so the present tense or even future tense may be appropriate.

Comment: but is it not the present continuous?

Answer (score 0):

Hypothetical situations
When we talk about things that we imagine (hypothetical situations) we use present tense forms after phrases like what if, in case, suppose to talk about the future if we think that this is a situation that is likely to happen:
You should take an umbrella in case it rains.
Take your phone. What if you need to contact me?

Answer (score 0):

Stories can be told in what is called **the historical present.**

"One day my mothers comes along and knocks on my door, and says. etc."

People often tell others about situations from the past using the present tense.

[The historical present](https://www.thoughtco.com/historical-present-verb-tense-1690928#:%7E:text=In%20English%20grammar%2C%20the%20%22historical,present%2C%20and%20narrative%20present.%22)